# оптимизация запросов в gredview yii2

Tags: yii2

Во вьюхе, выводящей список заказов, использую greedview, который, собственно и выводит эти заказы. Это модель Orders. Одним из столбцов этой таблицы является столбец (Provider - поставщик), которого я дёргаю из смежной таблицы Provider_profile.

Вот код, с которым у меня проблема.

```
 [

   'format' => 'raw',
   'label' => \Yii::t('app','Действия'),
   'value' => function ($model) {
       $provider = $model->provider;  // $model - это объект заказа, $provider - объект Поставщика, который я получаю по связи. Запрос в базу №1.
// Дальше я использую здесь же полученный объект $provider, обращаясь к его свойствам
           $tel = $provider->tel;  // Запрос в базу №2
           $mail = $provider->mail;  // Запрос в базу №3 

return $tel.','.$mail;
],
[...], // следующий столбец
[...]  // следующий столбец
```

Сами вопросы:

1. Почему создаются запросы №2 и №3? Я ведь уже кодом `$provider =
   $model->provider;` создал себе объект Поставщика и поместил его в
   переменную `$provider`. По сути обращения `$provider->tel` и
   `$provider->mail` не должны делать запросы в базу, а должны
   обратится к уже созданному объекту.
2. Как мне сделать так, чтоб я один раз создал себе объект в gredview и мог пользоваться им без увеличения количества запросов в
   базу? Как в данном случае сократить количество запросов с 3 до 1?
3. Как создать такой объект не только в пределах одной ячейки или столбца таблицы, а так, чтоб создав его один раз я мог пользоваться уже созданным объектом и в следующих столбцах этой же таблицы?

Буду очень благодарен, если ответы будут пронумерованы согласно номерам вопросов.

Comment: не gred и не greed, а 'grid' . "Почему создаются запросы №2 и №3?" - можете показать, где написано, что они создаются?

Comment: В debug панели показываются номера строк, создающих запросы

Comment: Там, где формируешь запрос AR, надо добавить `find()->with('provider')->all()`